# cmake + qt + vtk: Compilation errors in macOS Mojave

Tags: c++, macos, qt, cmake, vtk

I'm running macOS Mojave (10.14.3).
After the upgrade to Mojave *something* in my system changed and I no longer can compile code having `VTK` and `Qt`.

A (not) working example can be found in the examples given by [VTK](https://lorensen.github.io/VTKExamples/site/Cxx/Qt/SideBySideRenderWindowsQt/#download-and-build-sidebysiderenderwindowsqt).

It's worth to mention,  that I can compile the other examples not involving `qt`.

I use `homebrew` to install everything I need.

Hier are the logs:

```
cmake ..
-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 10.0.1.10010046
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 10.0.1.10010046
-- Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- VTK_VERSION: 8.1.2
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/chraibi/Downloads/VTK_Examples/SideBySideRenderWindowsQt/build
```

and

```
make 
In file included from /Users/user/Downloads/VTK_Examples/SideBySideRenderWindowsQt/build/SideBySideRenderWindowsQt_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp:2:
In file included from /Users/user/Downloads/VTK_Examples/SideBySideRenderWindowsQt/build/SideBySideRenderWindowsQt_autogen/EWIEGA46WW/moc_SideBySideRenderWindowsQt.cpp:9:
In file included from /Users/user/Downloads/VTK_Examples/SideBySideRenderWindowsQt/build/SideBySideRenderWindowsQt_autogen/EWIEGA46WW/../../../SideBySideRenderWindowsQt.h:6:
In file included from /usr/local/opt/qt/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers/QMainWindow:1:
In file included from /usr/local/opt/qt/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers/qmainwindow.h:44:
In file included from /usr/local/opt/qt/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers/qwidget.h:52:
/usr/local/opt/qt/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers/qsizepolicy.h:51:82: error: invalid token at start of a preprocessor expression
#if !defined(Q_CC_GNU) || defined(Q_CC_INTEL) || defined(Q_CC_CLANG) || Q_CC_GNU >= 408
                                                                                 ^
/usr/local/opt/qt/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers/qsizepolicy.h:68:1: error: unknown type name 'Q_DECL_CONST_FUNCTION'
Q_DECL_CONST_FUNCTION inline uint qHash(QSizePolicy key, uint seed = 0) Q_DECL_NOTHROW;
^
/usr/local/opt/qt/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers/qsizepolicy.h:68:23: error: expected unqualified-id
Q_DECL_CONST_FUNCTION inline uint qHash(QSizePolicy key, uint seed = 0) Q_DECL_NOTHROW;
                      ^
/usr/local/opt/qt/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers/qsizepolicy.h:91:5: error: unknown type name 'Q_ENUM'
    Q_ENUM(Policy)
    ^
/usr/local/opt/qt/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers/qsizepolicy.h:91:19: error: expected ';' at end of declaration list
    Q_ENUM(Policy)
                  ^
/usr/local/opt/qt/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers/qsizepolicy.h:110:35: error: use of undeclared identifier 'ControlType'
    Q_DECLARE_FLAGS(ControlTypes, ControlType)
                                  ^
/usr/local/opt/qt/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers/qsizepolicy.h:111:5: error: unknown type name 'Q_FLAG'
    Q_FLAG(ControlTypes)
    ^
/usr/local/opt/qt/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers/qsizepolicy.h:111:12: error: duplicate member 'ControlTypes'
    Q_FLAG(ControlTypes)
           ^
/usr/local/opt/qt/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers/qsizepolicy.h:110:21: note: previous declaration is here
    Q_DECLARE_FLAGS(ControlTypes, ControlType)
                    ^
/usr/local/opt/qt/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers/qsizepolicy.h:111:25: error: expected ';' at end of declaration list
    Q_FLAG(ControlTypes)
                        ^
/usr/local/opt/qt/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers/qsizepolicy.h:132:5: error: unknown type name 'Q_DECL_RELAXED_CONSTEXPR'
    Q_DECL_RELAXED_CONSTEXPR void setHorizontalPolicy(Policy d) Q_DECL_NOTHROW { bits.horPolicy = d; }
    ^
/usr/local/opt/qt/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers/qsizepolicy.h:132:30: error: expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers
    Q_DECL_RELAXED_CONSTEXPR void setHorizontalPolicy(Policy d) Q_DECL_NOTHROW { bits.horPolicy = d; }
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
/usr/local/opt/qt/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers/qsizepolicy.h:136:73: error: expected ';' at end of declaration list
    QT_SIZEPOLICY_CONSTEXPR Qt::Orientations expandingDirections() const Q_DECL_NOTHROW {
                                                                        ^
/usr/local/opt/qt/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers/qsizepolicy.h:153:58: error: expected ';' at end of declaration list
    QT_SIZEPOLICY_CONSTEXPR int horizontalStretch() const Q_DECL_NOTHROW { return static_cast<int>(bits.horStretch); }
                                                         ^
/usr/local/opt/qt/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers/qsizepolicy.h:176:47: error: expected ';' at end of declaration list
    QT_SIZEPOLICY_CONSTEXPR QSizePolicy(int i) Q_DECL_NOTHROW : data(i) { }
                                              ^
/usr/local/opt/qt/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers/qsizepolicy.h:178:50: error: unknown type name 'Bits'
    QT_SIZEPOLICY_CONSTEXPR explicit QSizePolicy(Bits b) Q_DECL_NOTHROW : bits(b) { }
                                                 ^
/usr/local/opt/qt/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers/qsizepolicy.h:178:57: error: expected ';' at end of declaration list
    QT_SIZEPOLICY_CONSTEXPR explicit QSizePolicy(Bits b) Q_DECL_NOTHROW : bits(b) { }
                                                        ^
/usr/local/opt/qt/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers/qsizepolicy.h:223:9: error: unknown type name 'Bits'
        Bits bits;
        ^
/usr/local/opt/qt/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers/qsizepolicy.h:231:33: error: use of undeclared identifier 'Q_RELOCATABLE_TYPE'; did you mean 'Q_MOVABLE_TYPE'?
Q_DECLARE_TYPEINFO(QSizePolicy, Q_RELOCATABLE_TYPE);
                                ^
/usr/local/include/QtCore/qglobal.h:2272:5: note: 'Q_MOVABLE_TYPE' declared here
    Q_MOVABLE_TYPE = 0x2,
    ^
In file included from /Users/user/Downloads/VTK_Examples/SideBySideRenderWindowsQt/build/SideBySideRenderWindowsQt_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp:2:
In file included from /Users/user/Downloads/VTK_Examples/SideBySideRenderWindowsQt/build/SideBySideRenderWindowsQt_autogen/EWIEGA46WW/moc_SideBySideRenderWindowsQt.cpp:9:
In file included from /Users/user/Downloads/VTK_Examples/SideBySideRenderWindowsQt/build/SideBySideRenderWindowsQt_autogen/EWIEGA46WW/../../../SideBySideRenderWindowsQt.h:6:
In file included from /usr/local/opt/qt/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers/QMainWindow:1:
In file included from /usr/local/opt/qt/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers/qmainwindow.h:44:
In file included from /usr/local/opt/qt/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers/qwidget.h:52:
/usr/local/opt/qt/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers/qsizepolicy.h:231:33: error: use of undeclared identifier 'Q_RELOCATABLE_TYPE'; did you mean 'Q_MOVABLE_TYPE'?
Q_DECLARE_TYPEINFO(QSizePolicy, Q_RELOCATABLE_TYPE);
                                ^
/usr/local/include/QtCore/qglobal.h:2272:5: note: 'Q_MOVABLE_TYPE' declared here
    Q_MOVABLE_TYPE = 0x2,
    ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/SideBySideRenderWindowsQt.dir/SideBySideRenderWindowsQt_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/SideBySideRenderWindowsQt.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Similar error I get with `cmake  -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++-8`, where g++-8 is installed with `brew`

Maybe I should mention, there is a [software](https://github.com/JuPedSim/homebrew-jps) using `vtk` and `qt` that I can install via `brew` without any problems. The same software cannot be compiled directly (cmake --> make).

Could be something with my OS is wrong?

Comment: I had a similar problem a few days ago. In my case, I had Qt4 and Qt5 both installed. I did upgrade to the latest version of Mojave and Xcode and then uninstalled Qt4. Also, add the system path to your compilation: "/usr/local/include" and "usr/local/lib" because Mojave is no longer including them in the system paths.

Comment: I know several people who do VTK development on Mojave(including myself) and it works fine. Which Qt are you using? Did you build VTK from source and set VTK_DIR in your example's CMakeCache?

Comment: Yeah for me too VTK works fine.. until I combine it with Qt. Then it's not fun anymore.  As you can see in the question, I use brew to install *everything*.. and it's not my example, but from VTK.

Comment: I have a similar issue with CMake + Qt5 + Catch2, when using `target_link_libraries(target Qt5::Widgets Catch2::Catch2)`. @Tengis have you ever managed to solve this?

Comment: Ok! So I had Qt 4 installed by Homebrew on my system, without knowing it! `brew uninstall qt` solved it. (I have Qt5 installed manually)

Comment: @khrykin Yes, I solved this problem, by *not* installing vtk and qt using brew. I compiled everything manually, and then it worked fine. I guess might have been a conflict between `libstd++` used by brew and `libc++` used when I compile my application. So at some point stuff goes south...

Answer (score 0):

Just uninstall the duplicate QT installations on your system, like the older qt4 version. Credits to khrykin

Comment: How can we check if we have multiple Qt installations on our system ?

Comment: @MarcoMag, there is no procedure that always works, but you need to look at the search paths of cmake and the compiler. In my case it found different versions with conflicting types, hence causing the error.